# Unable to use rosrun because of unknown syntax error

Tags: c++, syntax-error, ros

I am trying to run:

`rosrun myrobot keys.cpp`

But I am getting this error:

```
/home/kannachan/drone/src/quantum_drone/scripts/Controls/Keys.cpp: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/kannachan/drone/src/quantum_drone/scripts/Controls/Keys.cpp: line 6: `int getch() {'
```

I checked the program that I stole on the internet (to get keyboard input):

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "std_msgs/Int32.h"


int getch() {
    static struct termios oldt, newt;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);           
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);                
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);  
    int ch = getchar();                  
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt); 
    return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "keyboard");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int32>("/key", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);


    while (ros::ok())
    {

        std_msgs::Int32 c;
        c.data = getch();  
        pub.publish(c);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

I checked line 6 to see the syntax error, but from my experience in C++, there doesn't appear to be any syntax errors. The code was previously commented, but I removed it because it was causing issues with rosrun as well and now I have the following errors that I just do not understand what is going on.

Comment: I guess `getch` is a macro defined in some of included files

Comment: @S.M. i think i solved the asnwer. I tried to run the source file and not the compiled program. I tried `rosrun myrobot key` and it seems to work now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was being a moron: I think the reason why it couldn't work was that I was running the source file and not actual compiled program.

Solution:

```
rosrun myrobot key
```